# Desk audio streaming and shared speakers streaming options for an office?

Tags: networking, streaming, audio

I've been handed an interesting project and want to be sure about what I put in place.

We have several 'islands' of tables (different teams) and several users in heavy phone usage areas of the office.  They want a solution whereby each island of desks can control the volume on their desks only and individual users can listen to a the same music on their desktop/laptop etc.. (when it's not appropriate to have it loud).

The music is originating from Spotify, We7 etc..

I'm slightly proposing using some Apple Express units and some long cables (using Shairport to push the audio out) to several powered speakers (so I don't have to mess around with amplifiers) on the desk 'islands' and a local shoutcast server to serve the local desktop/laptop users (I understand the latency issue of 1-5 seconds).

Am I going the right way about this? or has anybody got a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

AirFoil would be my suggestion - http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/

It's basically the same idea as the Apple Airport express, but in software. One computer 'serves' the audio, all the others are clients.

Comment: How well does it 'sync' the music to 2 different destinations (using their own software)?
If 2 PC's are running the 'Airfoil Speakers for Windows' at different parts of the office will they be slightly out of sync or is there something within the software that is smart enough to keep all the sound in sync?

Comment: I haven't tested this myself, but it should keep all your speakers in sync.